# Segmentation fault with Homebrew php56-xdebug

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug

I've been running PHP 5.4 with xdebug on my Mac via Homebrew for a while, and yesterday I tried to upgrade to 5.6 with xdebug using the php56 and php56-xdebug formulas. I was able to get php56 working fine, but as soon as I install the php56-xdebug formula, Apache won't load, and I get a segmentation fault. If I remove php56-xdebug, everything works fine again. My php error log was showing that xdebug.so was trying to load twice, but I uninstalled everything php 5.4 (php54, php54-xdebug, etc.), so that went away. But for some reason, I can't get rid of my "Segmentation fault (11)" error message. I've triple checked my apache config settings and my xdebug.ini, and they are correct, as they always have been. I'm also not getting any errors in my PHP error log.

I've tried uninstalling php 5.6 itself, as well as the xdebug formula, all to no avail. Short of re-installing my OS, what do I need to do to get xdebug working?

Thanks.

**Update**: Per [this issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1646), I installed php56-xdebug using --build-from-source, but the result is the same.

Comment: did you update all of the build dependencies ?

Comment: Yes, I ran brew up, and everything is current.

Comment: it's not an OS issue, its a build issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem was [issues in the 2.3.x branch of xdebug](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1122). I ended up [manually compiling xdebug](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1569) 2.2.7 and got it to work that way.